# Reading bytes from a file and overwriting the same bytes

Tags: c++, c, file, fread

I'm using `fread` to read the contents of a file and I want to over-write the bytes I've just read. So let's say:

```
fread(buffer, buffersize, 1, FilePointer);
```

I want to overwrite the exact same bytes that I've just read. The size of buffer varies, but I want to overwrite the exact same amount of bytes I've just read.
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `fseek` then `fwrite`?

Comment: @Yakk, But wouldn't it append bytes instead of overwrite? Also is there a faster way instead of read/fseek/fwrite?

Comment: fread returns number of objects read.

Comment: Verify that your file was opened in read and write access; no other attributees (except maybe binary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do what you want.  I use `ftell()` to remember the starting position so that I don't have to worry about if `fread()` succeeded or failed.

```
filePos = ftell(FilePointer);
fread(buffer, buffersize, 1, FilePointer);
fseek(FilePointer, filePos, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(buffer2, buffersize, 1, FilePointer);
```

Keep in mind that if you are both reading and writing the same file, you need to make sure that you use `fflush()` or `fseek()` when you switch from reading to writing or vice versa.  If you don't, you get undefined behavior.   [You can read more about that here.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO39-C.+Do+not+alternately+input+and+output+from+a+stream+without+an+intervening+flush+or+positioning+call)

By the way, if you are looking for faster ways of reading/writing bytes in a file, you might want to look into using `mmap()` to map your file to memory.

Comment: @JS1 Should I do fflush after read? I do fread, then fseek and then fwrite, then again fread, fseek and fwrite. Should I do fflush after fwrite only?

Comment: Additionally `ftell()` may be useful for recording a file position to which to later `fseek()` to using `SEEK_SET`.  Note also that `mmap()` is a POSIX call.  In Windows has its own API for memory mapped files.  The Boost library provides a cross-platform interface to memory mapped files.

Comment: @Clifford, should I only use fflush after writes? Also after writing, my file pointer will be same as post-read, correct?

Comment: @JimmyC : `fflush()` is only defined for output streams, but there is no issue with performing interleaved I/O without flushing; the operation will be performed on the same buffer, `fflush()` only forces to the buffer to be committed to the file at a time of your choosing.  You will get better performance if you leave that decision to the OS which will ensure the file is consistent when it is closed.  You might want to flush if the same file were operated on by another process, but in that case a memory mapped file would be a better method in any case.

Comment: @Clifford, Thank you! I'll put it only after writes, one last question, when I read, then rewind and when I finally write same amount, my file pointer will be same as before, correct? I mean same as after fread

Comment: @JimmyC : If you want to be certain about the file pointer position, use `ftell()` to record it and `fseek()` to restore it.  Be certain to open the file in binary mode to avoid issues with line-end translations - in Windows a single `\n` will be translated to CR + LF in a text file, making `fseek()` produce unintended results.

Comment: @JimmyC :  That is not what I suggested; in most cases you need not (and should not) use `fflush()`at all.

Comment: @Clifford So finally, should I do fflush or not? You say I shouldn't and others say I should?!

Comment: You only need to have a nul op between read and write and vice versa. This can be flush or fseek, should you not want to move the file pointer fseek(FILE,0,SEEK_CUR). It should be faster to use fseek rather than fflush

Comment: Also a more correct answer would capture the number of bytes actually read and use that value for the fseek and fwrite proposed by @JS1, rather than assuming the bytes read and to write is bufsize

Comment: @rhubarbdog: Or avoid the hassle by using `fgetpos`/`fsetpos`.

Comment: @JimmyC : Follow the link in JS1's answer, it explains it clearly enough.  My advice was somewhat inaccurate, but you don't need the fflush() if you have already used fseek() (or fsetpos() for that matter).  Either way, it all becomes irrelevant if you use a memory mapped file whereby you simply treat the file as a random-access array of characters.

Comment: @Clifford: Or just read the file into memory unless performance is critical. That way you get newline translations and don't have to worry about `mmap` error handling (a problem so gnarly that the boost library doesn't even try)